# Saving Day to Firestore for the first time only in flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

After registering as a member of firebase, you are also trying to add data to the firestore
The code is as follows

```
await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid).set({
        '1_email' : FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.email,
        '2_name' : 'Null',
        '3_phone' : '01012345678',
        '4_age' : 20,
        }
      );
```

I want the data to be stored in the firestore only for the first time
So I tried to code it as follows, but I couldn't solve it

```
if(FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid) == null){
      await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid).set({
        '1_email' : FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.email,
        '2_name' : 'Null',
        '3_phone' : '01012345678',
        '4_age' : 20,
        }
      );
    }
```

What I thought was that if a document such as user uid is null in the fireestore, I added data, and if it is not null, I wrote a code in the form of leaving it alone, but I couldn't solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is meaningless:

```
if(FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid) == null){
```

You're checking whether a document **reference** is null, which is will never be. What you want to do, is check whether the document exists, for which you will have to try and read it from the database.

```
var ref = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid);
var snapshot = await ref.get();
if(!snapshot.exists){
  ...
}
```